# Want to define a record in Scheme48

Tags: scheme, scheme48

I've tried an example of define-record-type in scheme48 and it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong?

```
(define-record-type circle
 (make-circle r)
 circle?
 (r get-radius))
```

gives

```
Error: undefined variable
   circle
   (package user)
```

I've tried other examples and I get similar results. I've even tried an example straight out of the scheme48 user manual.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [manual](http://s48.org/0.57/manual/s48manual_42.html) is stated that a `record` is defined like this:

```
(define-record-type tag type-name
  (constructor-name field-tag ...)
  predicate-name
  (field-tag accessor-name [modifier-name])
  ...)
```

So in your example, it seems that the `type-name` is missing. Try this:

```
(define-record-type circle :circle
  (make-circle r)
  circle?
  (r get-radius))
```

And don't forget to import the library first:

```
,open define-record-types
```

Comment: @FredFinkle I updated my answer, try the last version - using only `:circle` as both tag and tag-name

Comment: @FredFinkle the above is working for me, are you importing the right libraries? in the [manual](http://s48.org/0.57/manual/s48manual_35.html) is stated that you must "Use the ,open command or the module language to open the structures described below"

Comment: @FredFinkle and try both `define-record-type circle :circle` and `define-record-type :circle` to see which one works for you

Comment: `,open define-record-types` worked. Is there anywhere that these libraries are specified rather than being implied as in the page you cite?

Comment: @FredFinkle not that I'm aware of, that's the official documentation and if it's not there...

Comment: @ÓscarLópez +1 for the `,open` command; very helpful to a newbie like me  ^_^